# Breaking the linkifier with pasted links containing unprintable chars

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

It seems [Oddthinking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/23/oddthinking) managed to break the automated linkifier while linking to a docx file. I'm not positive it has anything to do with .docx files, or perhaps urls without a `www.` prefix, but the effect can be found in this [sandbox answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178649/171697).

[Here's the question it occurred on](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16088/did-mosque-restorers-find-a-400-year-old-letter-from-the-architect-with-instruct) (now fixed, although I'm not sure what i did)

Edit: It wasn't related to the .docx extension at all, there are weird, non-printable chars in the URL. Could these be stripped out perhaps?

Comment: Very strange. Nothing appears to be wrong with the URL itself: http://gruart2010.edublogs.org/files/2010/09/Turkish_Interior_Design.docx

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - Exactly! There was nothing wrong I could see, but editing the post, deleting some of the url and typing it back in verbatim fixed it